# Uses of Hive database need to be password protected

Tags: hive

If someone wants to use a database in hive using command `hive> use database_name;` it should ask password.

I tried with Kerberos but didn't fulfil my requirement, because it is for complete cluster. How can I make use of password authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now Hive doesnt support password login while executing hive commands, but as part of security for hive databases and tables there is something called [sentry](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-manager/v5-0-0/Cloudera-Manager-Managing-Clusters/cm5mc_sentry_config.html) which can be used in your scenario.

You could easily restrict users based on their access levels as mentioned by the cluster administrators